# Landsat7 Scan Line Correction in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-7

I am working on a time series with Landsat 7 and I have issues with the scan line correction. I already saw the question  [LS7 filling the gaps image with google earth engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264061/ls7-filling-the-gaps-image-with-google-earth-engine) and tried to adopt the posted solution. I do not know why exactly the code does not work and if it is so, because the original post used raw scenes, and I am using surface reflectance.

I only changed few lines of this [GEE code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/55213e804bb0ae4414176c02ac280ae7) and used SR-Landsat scenes in my study area.
I always get the error in line 40

```
regress.ReduceNeighborhood is not a function
```

I normally get such an error, if an ImageCollection instead of an image it used, so I wonder, why this error appears.

```
var MIN_SCALE = 1/3;
var MAX_SCALE = 3;
var MIN_NEIGHBORS = 144;

/* Apply the USGS L7 Phase-2 Gap filling protocol, using a single kernel size. */
var GapFill = function(src, fill, kernelSize, upscale) {
  var kernel = ee.Kernel.square(kernelSize * 30, "meters", false)

  // Find the pixels common to both scenes.
  var common = src.mask().and(fill.mask())
  var fc = fill.updateMask(common)
  var sc = src.updateMask(common)
  Map.addLayer(common.select(0).mask(common.select(0)), {palette:['000000']}, 'common mask (both exist)', false)

  // Find the primary scaling factors with a regression.
  // Interleave the bands for the regression.  This assumes the bands have the same names.
  var regress = fc.addBands(sc)

  regress = regress.select(regress.bandNames().sort())
  print(regress,'regress')
  var ratio = 5

  if(upscale) {
    var fit = regress
      .ReduceResolution(ee.Reducer.median(), false, 500)
      .reproject(regress.select(0).projection().scale(ratio, ratio))
      .ReduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.linearFit().forEach(src.bandNames()), kernel, null, false)
      .unmask()
      .reproject(regress.select(0).projection().scale(ratio, ratio))
  } else {

    var fit = regress
      .ReduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.linearFit().forEach(src.bandNames()), kernel, null, false)
  }

  var offset = fit.select(".*_offset")
  var scale = fit.select(".*_scale")

  Map.addLayer(scale.select('B1_scale'), {min:-2, max:2}, 'scale B1', false)

  // Find the secondary scaling factors using just means and stddev
  var Reducer = ee.Reducer.mean().combine(ee.Reducer.stdDev(), null, true)

  if(upscale) {
    var src_stats = src
      .ReduceResolution(ee.Reducer.median(), false, 500)
      .reproject(regress.select(0).projection().scale(ratio, ratio))
      .ReduceNeighborhood(Reducer, kernel, null, false)
      .reproject(regress.select(0).projection().scale(ratio, ratio))

    var fill_stats = fill
      .ReduceResolution(ee.Reducer.median(), false, 500)
      .reproject(regress.select(0).projection().scale(ratio, ratio))
      .ReduceNeighborhood(Reducer, kernel, null, false)
      .reproject(regress.select(0).projection().scale(ratio, ratio))
  } else {
    var src_stats = src
      .ReduceNeighborhood(Reducer, kernel, null, false)

    var fill_stats = fill
      .ReduceNeighborhood(Reducer, kernel, null, false)
  }

  var scale2 = src_stats.select(".*stdDev").divide(fill_stats.select(".*stdDev"))
  var offset2 = src_stats.select(".*mean").subtract(fill_stats.select(".*mean").multiply(scale2))

  var invalid = scale.lt(MIN_SCALE).or(scale.gt(MAX_SCALE))
  Map.addLayer(invalid.select(0).mask(invalid.select(0)), {palette:['550000']}, 'invalid1', false)
  scale = scale.where(invalid, scale2)
  offset = offset.where(invalid, offset2)

  // When all else fails, just use the difference of means as an offset.  
  var invalid2 = scale.lt(MIN_SCALE).or(scale.gt(MAX_SCALE))
  Map.addLayer(invalid2.select(0).mask(invalid2.select(0)), {palette:['552020']}, 'invalid2', false)
  scale = scale.where(invalid2, 1)
  offset = offset.where(invalid2, src_stats.select(".*mean").subtract(fill_stats.select(".*mean")))

  // Apply the scaling and mask off pixels that didn't have enough neighbors.
  var count = common.ReduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.count(), kernel, null, true, "boxcar")
  var scaled = fill.multiply(scale).add(offset)
      .updateMask(count.gte(MIN_NEIGHBORS))

  return src.unmask(scaled, true)
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var etmCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
                    .filterDate('2005-05-30', '2005-10-30');
// Define a collection filter.
var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(area),
ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 30),  
  ee.Filter.lt('GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL', 10),
ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY', 9),
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI', 9)
  ));
// Filter collections and prepare them for merging.
var l7images = etmCol.filter(colFilter);
print(l7images,'Landsat 7')

var source    = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0))
var fill      = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(1))
Map.addLayer(fill,    {min:400, max:2500, gamma: 2.222 , bands:["B3", "B2", "B1"]}, "1", true)
Map.addLayer(source,  {min:400, max:2500, gamma: 2.222 , bands:["B3", "B2", "B1"]}, "2", true)
print(source,'First')
print(fill,'Second')
//var source  = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR/LE07_167063_20150207")
//var fill    = ee.Image(" LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR/LE07_167063_20150615")

var result = GapFill(source, fill, 10, false);
Map.addLayer(result,  {min:0, max:200, bands:["B3", "B2", "B1"]}, "filled", true)

var result = GapFill(source, fill, 10, true);
Map.addLayer(result,  {min:0, max:200, bands:["B3", "B2", "B1"]}, "filled (upscaled)", true)
```

Here is my code https://code.earthengine.google.com/690a5042671f6effed934d1f8e0ef01d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just start functions in the GEE with lowercase letters. Thus:

`reduceResolution()` and `reduceNeighborhood`

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3dc386f21d46e221a9a0ebbed415810b)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your code is spitting out an error, but it seems to be as part of the 'if-else' statement. I do not have a solution to your code, but I can offer another code that works without an if-else statement and also includes a cloud mask function. I obtained this from stackExchange, but I cannot remember who wrote the original code. Just supply a variable `point` that is your AOI.

```
var cloudMaskL7 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                    .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var l7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
    .map(cloudMaskL7);

var kernelSize = 10;
var kernel = ee.Kernel.square(kernelSize * 30, 'meters', false);

var GapFill = function(image) {
  var start = image.date().advance(-1, 'year');
  var end = image.date().advance(1, 'year');
  var fill = l7.filterDate(start, end).median();
  var regress = fill.addBands(image); 
  var regress = regress.select(regress.bandNames().sort());
  var fit = regress.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.linearFit().forEach(image.bandNames()), kernel, null, false);
  var offset = fit.select('.*_offset');
  var scale = fit.select('.*_scale');
  var scaled = fill.multiply(scale).add(offset);
  return image.unmask(scaled, true);
};

// TESTING CODE

Map.centerObject(point, 11);

var check = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterBounds(point)
    .filterDate('2004-06-15', '2004-12-31');
var checkImage = ee.Image(check.first());
var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 200, max: 5500};
Map.addLayer(checkImage, visParams, 'source');

// Test composite.
var checkStart = checkImage.date().advance(-1, 'year');
var checkEnd = checkImage.date().advance(1, 'year');
var composite = l7.filterDate(checkStart, checkEnd).median();
Map.addLayer(composite, visParams, 'median');

// Rough implementation for comparison.
var replaced = checkImage.unmask(composite);
Map.addLayer(replaced, visParams, 'simple');

// Fancy implementation.
var filled = ee.Image(check.map(GapFill).first());
Map.addLayer(filled, visParams, 'filled');
```