# Scan Line Error Landsat7 GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, landsat-7

I have a code that works, but I want assistance on how the scan line error in GEE can be fixed. The link to the code is below:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmpalasimbarashe%2FProject1%3AKNDVI%20L5

```
/// IMPORTING THE FEATURE COLLECTION ///
var points = points.map(function(feature){
  var sample_id = feature.get('Sample_ID');
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), {'id': feature.id()})
    .set('Sample_ID', sample_id);
});

Map.addLayer(points,{color:'green'},'Root Locations');
Map.centerObject(points,10);
print(points);

var points_list = points.toList(points.size());

var keys = points_list.map(function (ele) {

  return ee.Feature(ele).get('id');
  
});

var values = points_list.map(function (ele) {

  return ee.Feature(ele).get('Sample_ID');
  
});

var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, values);


////Cloud Masking//////
var cloudMask = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
          .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
          .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3))
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var cloud_perc = 10;//Max cloud percentile per scene.   

/// DATE RANGE FOR THE TIME SERIES ///
var startDate =  new Date ('2010-09-01')
var endDate =  new Date ('2022-05-30')

/// COMPUTING THE KNDVI ////
var addKNDVI = function(image){
  
  var RED = image.select('B3');
  var NIR = image.select('B4');
  
  /// COMPUTE D2 A RENAME TO d2 ///
  var D2 = NIR.subtract(RED).pow(2)
    .select([0],['d2']);
 
  /// GAMMA DEFINED AS 1/sigma^2
  var gamma = ee.Number(4e6).multiply(-2.0);

/// COMPUTE KERNEL (k) AND KNDVI ///

  var k = D2.divide(gamma).exp();
  var kndvi = ee.Image.constant(1)
    .subtract(k).divide(ee.Image.constant(1).add(k))
    .select([0],['kndvi']).clip(points);
    
     return image.addBands(ee.Image([kndvi]));
 
};

/// IMPORTING THE IMAGE COLLECTION /////

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
                   .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  .map(addKNDVI)
                  .map(cloudMask)
                  //.map(maskQuality)
                  //.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than',10)
                 .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(points))
                 .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', cloud_perc));
                   
/// VIEWING THE MAX IN THE COMPOSITE ////
 var vizParams = { bands: ['B3','B2','B1'] , min: 0, max: 2000}
 Map.addLayer(collection.max(),vizParams, 'collection')

var testPoint = ee.Feature(points.first());
print(testPoint)
print(collection)
//Map.centerObject(testPoint, 10)

/// TIMESERIES CHART FOR SINGLE LOCATION ///
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: collection.select('kndvi'),
    region: testPoint.geometry()
    }).setOptions({
      interpolateNulls: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'KNDVI over Time at a Single Location',
      vAxis: {title: 'KNDVI'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'YYYY-MMM', gridlines: {count: 12}}
    })
print(chart)

//// TIMESERIES CHART FOR MULTIPLE LOCATIONS ////
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: collection.select('kndvi'),
    regions: points,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
})
print(chart)

/// HANDLING MASKED PIXELS ///
var triplets = collection.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('kndvi').reduceRegions({
    collection: points, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(['kndvi']), 
    scale: 10,
  })// reduceRegion doesn't return any output if the image doesn't intersect
    // with the point or if the image is masked out due to cloud
    // If there was no ndvi value found, we set the ndvi to a NoData value -9999
    .map(function(feature) {
    var kndvi = ee.List([feature.get('kndvi'), -9999])
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
    return feature.set({'kndvi': kndvi, 'imageID': image.id()})
    })
  }).flatten();
  
var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId); 
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });
         
  return joined.map(function(row) {
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
           return [feature.get(colId),ee.Number(feature.get('kndvi')).format('%.3f')];
        });
      return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
    });
};
var Results = format(triplets, 'id', 'imageID');

print("testPoint", testPoint);


//// EXPORTING MULTIPLE LOCATION TIMESERIES ///
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: Results,
    description: 'Multiple_Locations_KNDVI_time_series',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'Kndvi_time_series_multiple',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LS7 filling the gaps image with Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264061/ls7-filling-the-gaps-image-with-google-earth-engine)

Comment: I have gone through it and don't really understand how it can be incorporated into my code. My coding skills are basic.